# ImproperlyConfigured - UserRegisterView is missing a QuerySet. Define UserRegisterView.model, UserRegisterView.queryset, or override

Tags: python, django

sorry to be a bother. I have just created a user login app for a blog site, but I keep getting this error whenever I try to go to the registration page:

"UserRegisterView is missing a QuerySet. Define UserRegisterView.model, UserRegisterView.queryset, or override UserRegisterView.get_queryset()."

Below is my view.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_Class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
```

I'm not entirely sure where I need to go from here. Any help/explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: Typo: `form_Class` should be `form_class` (Notice capital `C` vs small `c`)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the errors carefully it may save you a lot of time. In this case, the error is quite self-explanatory:

```
UserRegisterView is missing a QuerySet.
```

Meaning, the view does not know where to get the data from/to.

And then, it tells you how to fix it:

```
Define UserRegisterView.model, UserRegisterView.queryset, 
or override UserRegisterView.get_queryset().
```

It gives you three options:

1. You can define a `model` property inside the view:

   ```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
        model = User  # it would be better settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, but that is outside the scope of the question.
        form_class = UserCreationForm
        template_name = 'registration/register.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
   ```
2. Or you can define a `queryset` property inside the view:

   ```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        form_class = UserCreationForm
        template_name = 'registration/register.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
   ```
3. Or you can override the `get_queryset` method of the view:

   ```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
        form_class = UserCreationForm
        template_name = 'registration/register.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

        def get_queryset(self):
            return User.objects.all()
   ```

Comment: Although you do say correct things but the main problem here is only that typo. A `CreateView` will only try to call `get_queryset` if the `form_class` (there was a typo here) is not defined, otherwise it does not really need a queryset. You should refrain from answering questions that are _only_ caused by typos as they are not very useful to people and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your time and for answering the question. Embarrassingly, it was a typo causing the issue!

Really appreciate your time!